# systemd unit verification fails while running Chef Client

Tags: chef-infra, systemd

We are leveraging Chef to install a Hazelcast. Hazelcast is installed as a systemd unit. However during installation it fails with the following error:

```
      Chef::Exceptions::ValidationFailed
      ----------------------------------
      Proposed content for /etc/systemd/system/hazelcast.service failed verification :systemd_unit (Chef::Resource::File::Verification::SystemdUnit)
      
      Compiled Resource:
      ------------------
      # Declared in 
      
      file("/etc/systemd/system/hazelcast.service") do
        action [:create]
        default_guard_interpreter :default
        content "[Unit]\nDescription = Hazelcast service. This file was generated via Chef. If you have changes that need to be applied to this file, please update the corresponding template rather than applying rogue changes\nAfter = network.target\n\n[Service]\nEnvironment = JAVA_OPTS=-Dlog4j.configurationFile=/opt/hazelcast/hazelcast-enterprise-4.0.1/bin/log4j.xml -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/opt/certs/cacerts.jks -DjaasLdapPropertiesFile=/opt/hazelcast/hazelcast-enterprise-4.0.1/bin/jaas-ldap.properties -Dhazelcast.security.permissions.operation.on-join=SEND -Dhazelcast.cluster.version.auto.upgrade.enabled=true -javaagent:/opt/newrelic/newrelic.jar -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.LogManager -Djava.security.properties=/opt/hazelcast/hazelcast-enterprise-4.0.1/bin/java-security-overrides.properties -Dcom.sun.net.ssl.checkRevocation=true -Dcom.sun.security.enableCRLDP=true -Dhazelcast.cluster.version.auto.upgrade.min.cluster.size=2\nWorkingDirectory = /opt/hazelcast/hazelcast-enterprise-4.0.1/bin\nExecStart = /opt/hazelcast/hazelcast-enterprise-4.0.1/bin/start.sh\nType = simple\nPIDFile = /opt/hazelcast/hazelcast-enterprise-4.0.1/bin/hazelcast_instance.pid\nExecStop = /opt/hazelcast/hazelcast-enterprise-4.0.1/bin/stop.sh\nExecStopPost = /bin/wait $MAINPID\nUser = hazelcast\nGroup = hazelcast\nLimitNOFILE = 65536\nSendSIGKILL = no\nTimeoutStopSec = 1900\n\n[Install]\nWantedBy = multi-user.target\n"
        owner "root"
        group "root"
        mode "0644"
        path "/etc/systemd/system/hazelcast.service"
        verifications [#<Chef::Resource::File::Verification:0x00000000086eb380 @command_opts={}, @command=:systemd_unit, @block=nil, @parent_resource=<file[/etc/systemd/system/hazelcast.service] @name: "/etc/systemd/system/hazelcast.service" @before: nil @params: {} @provider: nil @allowed_actions: [:nothing, :create, :delete, :touch, :create_if_missing] @action: [:create] @updated: false @updated_by_last_action: false @source_line: nil @guard_interpreter: nil @default_guard_interpreter: :default @elapsed_time: 0 @content: "[Unit]\nDescription = Hazelcast service. This file was generated via Chef. If you have changes that need to be applied to this file, please update the corresponding template rather than applying rogue changes\nAfter = network.target\n\n[Service]\nEnvironment = JAVA_OPTS=-Dlog4j.configurationFile=/opt/hazelcast/hazelcast-enterprise-4.0.1/bin/log4j.xml -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/opt/certs/cacerts.jks -DjaasLdapPropertiesFile=/opt/hazelcast/hazelcast-enterprise-4.0.1/bin/jaas-ldap.properties -Dhazelcast.security.permissions.operation.on-join=SEND -Dhazelcast.cluster.version.auto.upgrade.enabled=true -javaagent:/opt/newrelic/newrelic.jar -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.LogManager -Djava.security.properties=/opt/hazelcast/hazelcast-enterprise-4.0.1/bin/java-security-overrides.properties -Dcom.sun.net.ssl.checkRevocation=true -Dcom.sun.security.enableCRLDP=true -Dhazelcast.cluster.version.auto.upgrade.min.cluster.size=2\nWorkingDirectory = /opt/hazelcast/hazelcast-enterprise-4.0.1/bin\nExecStart = /opt/hazelcast/hazelcast-enterprise-4.0.1/bin/start.sh\nType = simple\nPIDFile = /opt/hazelcast/hazelcast-enterprise-4.0.1/bin/hazelcast_instance.pid\nExecStop = /opt/hazelcast/hazelcast-enterprise-4.0.1/bin/stop.sh\nExecStopPost = /bin/wait $MAINPID\nUser = hazelcast\nGroup = hazelcast\nLimitNOFILE = 65536\nSendSIGKILL = no\nTimeoutStopSec = 1900\n\n[Install]\nWantedBy = multi-user.target\n" @owner: "root" @group: "root" @mode: "0644" @path: "/etc/systemd/system/hazelcast.service" @verifications: [...]>>]
      end
      
      System Info:
      ------------
      chef_version=14.7.17
      platform=oracle
      platform_version=7.8
      ruby=ruby 2.5.3p105 (2018-10-18 revision 65156) [x86_64-linux]
      program_name=chef-client worker: ppid=14614;start=10:21:13;
      executable=/opt/chef/bin/chef-client
```

As can be seen from the log above, there is a verification failure. I checked out the content part of the file resource, and everything seems to be in place. Checked out few post online. Some suggestions were around using a later version (11.0.5) of chef-client. We rely on 14.7.17. Most of the posts talked about missing out on some configuration or some parameter defined incorrectly. However, I couldn't find anything specific.
Appreciate any leads!!

Comment: I may have found the issue. Testing it out.

Answer (score 0):

So, the issue was with the service file configurations. There were mainly two issues:

1. Environment attribute: Since, there was space in the value of environment attribute as single quote was needed to surround it.
2. ExecStop: The file that I was looking for `stop.sh` did not exist. Instead the file was named as `stop-all.sh`

Correcting the two errors above resolved the issue.